# Install Dart's package using Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, dart, ansible, dart-pub

I've the following Ansible task to install Dart:

```
---

# Install Dart

# Based on:
# - https://www.dartlang.org/install/linux#using-apt-get
# - https://github.com/jgrowl/ansible-dart

- name: install apt-transport-https required by Dart
  apt: pkg=apt-transport-https update_cache=yes state=latest

# Get the Google Linux package signing key.
- apt_key: url=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub state=present

# Set up the location of the stable repository.
- name: download dart source list
  get_url: url=https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list dest=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list mode=0644

# Set up for the dev channel
# Before running this command, follow the instructions in
# "Set up for the stable channel".
#$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_unstable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_unstable.list'
- apt: name=dart update_cache=yes state=present

- name: Add dart and tools to PATH
  template: src=dart.sh.j2 dest=/etc/profile.d/dart.sh owner=root group=root mode=0655
  notify:
     - install stagehand
```

It seems to install correctly Dart. The problem is when I notify `install stagehand` at the end. That handler is as follows

```
---

# Called after installing Dart to install Dart's package stagehand
- name: install stagehand
  shell: pub global activate stagehand
```

But I keep receiving the following errors:

```
...

TASK [install stagehand] *******************************************************
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "pub global activate stagehand", "delta": "0:00:00.001392", "end": "2017-02-13 02:03:06.679762", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-02-13 02:03:06.678370", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: pub: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
    to retry, use: --limit 

@/Users/X/Desktop/path_to_project/provision/ansible/playbook.retry
```

which is very strange because if I try to login to the Vagrant VM using `vagrant ssh` and I type `pub`, the packager manager of Dart is installed!

Since I'm very new to Ansible as well as all other technologies that I'm using, this could also be a problem caused becaused I still don't know exactly how Ansible works.

**Edit**

This the file (i.e. `dart.sh.j2`) that theoretically should export also `pub`:

```
# Add vendor binaries to the path
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin
```

**Edit 2**

Here's the `Vagrantfile` (as requested):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"  
  end

  # Run Ansible from the Vagrant Host
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "provision/ansible/playbook.yml"
  end

end
```

Comment: `pub` is not in the path. Most likely the script setting the path is not sourced in non-interactive shell session. You have not included the `dart.sh.j2`, so it's hard to answer what is the best workaround.

Comment: @techraf Included `dart.sh.j2`.

Comment: Use the full path to `pub`. But it's still unclear for me what it does, if `pub` sets the environment for a shell session, it won't be reflected anywhere.

Comment: Are you running the provision as part of Vagrant provision? Can you include your Vagrantfile as well?

Comment: @SztupY Yes. Added the vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by *SztupY*, I managed to *activate* Dart's package `stagehand` inside the Vagrant VM, `ubuntu/trusty64`.

These are the tools I used with their corresponding versions (in case somebody ends up in this post because of a similar problem):

```
+=================+============================+=========================================================+
|      Tool       |            Version         |                         Comments                        |
+=================+============================+=========================================================+
| Ansible         |   2.2.1.0                  |  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides  |
+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Vagrant         |  1.9.1                     |                                                         |
+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| ubuntu/trusty64 | (virtualbox, 20170202.1.0) |                                                         |
+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| ansible-dart    |                            |    Source: https://github.com/nbro/ansible-dart         |
+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I placed the downloaded folder of the Github project [`ansible-dart`](https://github.com/nbro/ansible-dart) under the folder `roles`, which is under the main folder of the provision folder (which in my case I called `provision/ansible`), which contains the `playbook.yml` file.

```
- name: provisioning project...

  hosts: all

  roles:
    - { role: ansible-dart, when: ansible_os_family == "Debian", become: true }

  tasks:
    - name: "add .pub-cache to PATH"
      lineinfile:
        dest: /home/vagrant/.profile
        line: 'PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/.pub-cache/bin'

    - name: activate Dart's package 'stagehand'
      shell: bash -lc "pub global activate stagehand"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `dart.sh` is not sourced for non-interactive, non-login shell sessions. That's why you will see different results when logged in interactively and when running scripts thorough SSH.

Given the file content, use the full path to `pub` executable (likely, you don't need `shell` module here and `command` is sufficient):

```
# Called after installing Dart to install Dart's package stagehand
- name: install stagehand
  command: /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub global activate stagehand
```

Comment: While I've not more the error, after I logged in to the VM, and I try to list the globally available Dart packages using `pub global list`, I've receive no results (so I suppose it was not installed). Indeed `stagehand` was not even added to the PATH, whereas on my host machine it was added automatically when I installed `stagehand`.

Comment: @nbro I had a look at the `pub` source code and could not find any obvious reason. But I have no experience with it. The word `activate` suggests some environment settings (like in Conda, or Virtualenv), but on the other hand, there is nothing obvious. You can try running the following task `shell: /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub global activate stagehand && /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub global list` in Ansible. Register the output and display it with `debug`. If the package shows there, then it's clearly a current environment problem.

Comment: Same as before: stagehand is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your solution.

The first one is, that by default the `shell` command uses a non-interactive, non-login shell, so it will completely skip running `/etc/profile.d/dart.sh`, and hence your `PATH` additions.

If you however use a login shell, it will work fine, as login shells do read `/etc/profile.d`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: install stagehand
      shell: bash -lc "pub global activate stagehand"
```

The second problem is that pub by default will install all packages into `~/.pub-cache/bin`, which is also not in your `PATH` (also note it will only install it for the calling user: `vagrant`, so it won't be available for other users). Changing `PATH` in the `vagrant` user's profile can be done for example with `lineinfile`.

A full, working playbook example:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: ansible-dart, when: ansible_os_family == "Debian", become: yes }

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "Add pub cache to PATH"
      lineinfile:
        dest: /home/vagrant/.profile
        line: 'PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/.pub-cache/bin'

    - name: install stagehand
      shell: bash -lc "pub global activate stagehand"
```

You can put this under `provision/ansible/playbook.yml` and clone `ansible-dart` into the `provision/ansible/roles` directory. The original `ansible-dart` seemed to have been a bit outdated, so I added some minor fixes to [my fork](https://github.com/sztupy/ansible-dart/commit/ac3ad16a8809d0c9ae96e164b0de1609285b0623), which includes using `become` instead of `sudo`, and installing `unzip`, as that's required now.

Example run:

```
$ vagrant up
(...)
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [ansible-dart : include] **************************************************
included: provision/ansible/roles/ansible-dart/tasks/Debian.yml for default
(...)
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Add pub cache to PATH] ***************************************************
changed: [default]

TASK [install stagehand] *******************************************************
changed: [default]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
default                    : ok=12   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=0
$ vagrant ssh -c stagehand
Welcome to Stagehand! We collect anonymous usage statistics and crash reports in
order to improve the tool. Would you like to opt-in to
additional analytics to help us improve Stagehand [y/yes/no]?
```

If you don't want to use `bash -lc` all the time, then you have to set the `PATH` value manually inside your playbooks. This is useful if you want to manage this computer mainly through ansible, and don't really require interactive terminal access:

```
- hosts: all
  environment:
    PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/home/vagrant/.pub-cache/bin"
  tasks:   
    - name: install stagehand
      shell: pub global activate stagehand
```

Obviously you can mix the two methods as well if required.

Comment: I've a few questions. 1. As far as I've understood that project was created for Debian VMs, whereas I'm using Ubuntu. Do you think it should work also for Ubuntu VMs? 2. Why do you say `unzip` is required? 3. Is connecting to the Vagrant machine using `vagrant ssh -c stagehand` necessary, i.e. is executing the command `stagehand` necessary, or did you do it just to show us that it's been installed? 4. I tried just to use your last solution involving setting the `PATH` under the `environment` and I'm getting an error saying that `ansible_env` is not defined.

Comment: @nbro 1. no, it doesn't matter. That package installs dart fine (if you do an ssh dart will be there), but it's not complete, and it has some issues. Using some of my suggestions you can fix those issues. From what I see that package is not official, and not maintained anyway. 2. When I tried it ansible died for me missing the unzip package. Adding it solved the problem 3. This is just an example showing that my solution work (e.g. you can connect to the machine and you have stagehand up and running)

Comment: 4. You might have added `gather_facts: no` somewhere in your playbook. Note I was using ansible 2.0.1.0, vagrant 1.9.1, VirtualBox 5.1 and OSX Sierra

Comment: Yes, I the versions are the problem, since (from what I've been looking around regarding the error) it seems that Ansible has changed... I'm using the version 2.2.1.0. Also by not using that solution, but instead just using `bash -lc` before the `pub` command, I've another error saying ` "stderr": "stdin: is not a tty\nglobal: pub: command not found"`. Note that I'm not using the package from Github, but my file to install Dart, which is based on that package. I simply removed the installation of Dartium and simplified things a little bit.

Comment: @nbro I just upgraded to ansible 2.2.1.0 and my solution is still working fine without any modification. Have you tried running my solution first (and only) without any of your modification / addition. As I don't know what you have changed / modified / added, I won't be able to debug it

Comment: Are you sure your `playbook.yml` file is correct? You have twice `hosts:all`, and as an item in a list, not under the the `name:...`

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42354354/3924118) which is really based on your first option, but I've also forked the same Github repository to accommodate some changes for my particular case. I would rather have another question. I tried to activate `stagehand` from the `main.yml` file inside the folder `ansible-dart/tasks`, and for some reason from there it doesn't work, instead I really need to do it in the `playbook.yml`. Any ideas why?